# count the number of pings that a machine is receiving

Tags: linux, network-programming, ping

I have a setup of two machines.
one will initiate pings and the other will be receiving.
now, i'd like to count the number of pings that are being received by the machine that is receiving the pings.

is there any way to accomplish that?

i tried googling but all i get is how to use the 'count' option of the ping command.. i.e., ping -c ...

i found some package called Net::Ping... but even that was of no help because that does the same as the normal ping command.( checks if a host is alive or not)

Can someone help me out with this please.
i am trying to write an algorithm that detects a ping attack
so i need the number of pings that my machine is receiving.

thanks!

Comment: From http://superuser.com/questions/348327/linux-how-to-monitor-incoming-pings: `tcpdump ip proto \\icmp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tcpdump 'icmp[icmptype] = icmp-echo'
```

Then count with i.e. wc the number of lines